# How to secure Epson Beamer?

Tags: network, mobile, protection

I work in a school and we have several Epson Beamers but some of our students have download an application for their mobile (with infra-red and WiFi connection) and they now have remote control and the ability to shut the projectors down.

How to protect an Epson Beamer against people with such application? With an password or access control list (compatible with the normal remote control, against the app)?

Comment: I don't think that there will no answer that can't be given directly from the Epson support. Did you contact them? And if there could nothing be done on there side, i don't really think that a school will pay a counter-measure against a infra-red or wifi connection to a beam but will instead a other Beamer which don't have this functions.

Comment: I don't contact the support because I don't know what type of beame and 88% of the beamer are epson. And almost all of this beamers has this function. Students shut down the beamer in the lesson when you don't see it. I want to know how to prevend this.

Comment: when you don't know what type of epson beamer, how should we know how to help you? ;-) I think even epson hast thousands of different configuration options. And you could read the Part Number or Product description and contact the Epson support with this Informations. I don't see how to help you to prevent your Students to connect to the Beamer if they to that with infra-red as example (block the infra red light?) without knowing which Beamer you use. (and i think that 88% are a little bit to high ;-) )

Comment: 88% of the beamers in the school. I want to know how to block this in the menu or network admin setting of the beamer. And by epson is that almost the same by all beamers

Comment: would that here help?`http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&infoType=FAQ&oid=207665&prodoid=63093461&foid=217153

Comment: I hope it will work, I see it tommorow can you send this as answer then can I if it works accept him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are low tech solutions that will work:

[image: Directional IR Field Limitation Device]

Possibly combined with an IR repeater:

[image: IR Repeater]

if you want to limit the remote control to, say the front of the room where the teacher stands.  That won't help if your teachers want to stroll around the students and operate the Beamer; as @AJHenderson says, there is no security protocol for the existing remotes.

Lacking a preventative control, you'll need to use corrective controls - DETENTION!

Answer (score 4):

Electrical tape works wonders.  If you still need to be able to remote control, you will need your own IR transmitter to tape to the receiver and a more secure triggering system for the IR transmitter taped directly to it.

There is no way to use the existing remotes in a secure manner.